# html css table locking using 2 tables

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to emulate a table column locking by creating 2 tables side by side. When the screen is to small only the 2nd table should be scrollable.

How do I do that?

I have 2 issues: the container does not size up to the screen (which I am emulating with fixed size div) and the right side would not scroll unless I provide a fixed max-width.

```css
.tbl-ct {
    border: blue 1px dashed;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.tbl-locked {
    border: lime 1px dotted;
    display: table-cell;
}

.tbl-main {
    border: cyan 1px dotted;
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 300px; border: red 1px solid;">
            <div class="tbl-ct">
                <table class="tbl-locked">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Column1</th>
                        <th>Column2</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Value11</td>
                        <td>Value12</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Value21</td>
                        <td>Value22</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table class="tbl-main">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Column3</th>
                        <th>Column4</th>
                        <th>Column5</th>
                        <th>Column6</th>
                        <th>Column7</th>
                        <th>Column8</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Value13</td>
                        <td>Value14</td>
                        <td>Value15</td>
                        <td>Value16</td>
                        <td>Value17</td>
                        <td>Value18</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Value23</td>
                        <td>Value24</td>
                        <td>Value25</td>
                        <td>Value26</td>
                        <td>Value27</td>
                        <td>Value28</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use mediaqueries ..https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#syntax_improvements_in_level_4

Comment: Not really in that sense: I can have a large screen with 100s of columns, I would still need to scroll the right side. That is the problem I am trying to solve which does not depend on the media size.

Comment: You don't necessarily need separate elements - why not use `position: sticky;` instead?

Comment: Yes, sticky works but I don't know how to do that with just one (table) element. I would need to specify a `left`  style for all sticky columns. For the first column it is fine, the subsequent ones depend on how wide the previous columns are. I have never used `position: sticky`  so I might be missing some details.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `position: sticky;` after a suggestion from the comment. There is a visual glitch that I don't know how to fix.

```css
.tbl-ct {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.tbl th {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tbl th:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: crimson;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tbl th:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: crimson;
  min-width: 120px;
  max-width: 120px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tbl td {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}

.tbl td:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: sticky;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tbl td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: sticky;
  min-width: 120px;
  max-width: 120px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 400px; border: red 1px solid;">
            <div class="tbl-ct">
                <table class="tbl">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Column1</th>
                          <th>Column2</th>
                          <th>Column3</th>
                          <th>Column4</th>
                          <th>Column5</th>
                          <th>Column6</th>
                          <th>Column7</th>
                          <th>Column8</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Value11</td>
                          <td>Value12</td>
                          <td>Value13</td>
                          <td>Value14</td>
                          <td>Value15</td>
                          <td>Value16</td>
                          <td>Value17</td>
                          <td>Value18</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Value21</td>
                          <td>Value22</td>
                          <td>Value23</td>
                          <td>Value24</td>
                          <td>Value25</td>
                          <td>Value26</td>
                          <td>Value27</td>
                          <td>Value28</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Value31</td>
                          <td>Value32</td>
                          <td>Value33</td>
                          <td>Value34</td>
                          <td>Value35</td>
                          <td>Value36</td>
                          <td>Value37</td>
                          <td>Value38</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Value41</td>
                          <td>Value42</td>
                          <td>Value43</td>
                          <td>Value44</td>
                          <td>Value45</td>
                          <td>Value46</td>
                          <td>Value47</td>
                          <td>Value48</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```